# How to use async/await inside closure of `Option::and_then` or `Option::map` without using OptionFuture?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-futures

I would like to run something like the following code:

```rust
async fn get_user(s: &str) -> Option<User> { /* ... */ }

let user_id = Some("sessiontoken").and_then(|session_token| {
    get_user(session_token)
        .await // <- error
        .map(|user| user.id)
});
```

But it doesn't work because await can only be used inside async blocks or functions.
If, on the other hand, I use an async block, the closure would return `impl Future<Output = Option<_>>` which is not allowed because `Option::and_then` only allows `Option` as a return type.

The only alternative I know would be to use `OptionFuture`, create an intermediate variable and `.map` instead of `.and_then`.

```rust
use futures::future::OptionFuture;

let user: OptionFuture<_> = Some("sessiontoken")
    .map(|session_token| {
        get_user(session_token)
    })
    .into();
let user_id = user.await.flatten().map(|user| user.id);
```

But this is really cumbersome and prevents me from using many functions that would operate on Options, Results or similar, such as `Option::and_then`.

Is there no better way?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the idiomatic way would be to simply use `match`:

```
let user_id = match session_token {
    Some(session_token) => get_user("sessiontoken").await.map(|user| user.id),
    None => None,
};
```

Comment: I was really expecting some kind of transpose method. `Option<Future<T>>` -> `Future<Option<T>>`. Then you could do something like `session_token.transpose().await`

Comment: @BrandonDyer I would definitely appreciate it if `Option<Future>` were more ergonomic, but alas that is not the case and nothing has changed recently AFAIK. The Rust team may be waiting on [`IntoFuture`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.IntoFuture.html) to stabilize since I believe there was potential confusion if `Option<Future>` implemented `Future` directly. Also related: [How do I transpose a Future out of an Option?](/q/69154566/2189130)

Answer (score 0):

While `match` is idiomatic, it is also possible to write your own combinator:

```rust
#[async_trait]
trait AsyncMap<T, U, F>
where
    F: FnOnce(T) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = U> + Send>> + Send,
{
    type Output;
    async fn async_map(self, map: F) -> Self::Output;
}

#[async_trait]
impl<T, U, F> AsyncMap<T, U, F> for Option<T>
where
    T: Send,
    U: Send,
    F: 'static + FnOnce(T) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = U> + Send>> + Send,
{
    type Output = Option<U>;
    async fn async_map(self, map: F) -> Self::Output {
        match self {
            Some(t) => {
                let u = map(t).await;
                Some(u)
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Then, as long as you have `AsyncMap` in scope, you can use it like

```rust
let foo = Some(123);
let bar = foo.as_ref().async_map(|value| Box::pin(async move {
    // probably in real life you would do something async here
    value.to_string() 
})).await;
assert_eq!(bar.unwrap(), "123");
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4befc326450e3612311a080a0848471a)