# What's the functional approach to replace this match block?

Tags: rust

What's the functional approach to replace the below `match`?

```rust
match second_db.player_create(player_id).await {
    Ok(o) => Ok(o),
    
    Err(err) => {
        first_db.player_delete(player_id).await?;

        Err(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "functional approach"? Match statements are usually considered to be quite a functional pattern.

Comment: I don't think it could be reduced any further, because you return a value from inside of your match statement. Also you have bizarre control flow. Why do you want to delete a player when it's creation failed? And why you return error to the caller when it fails? It seems to me that you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: If you're looking for an approach with chained methods, there is `.or_else()` to chain a failed result into a fallible lambda (much like `.and_then()` for the successful case). However, you won't be able to use that here since those methods are not async-agnostic. What you have is probably the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the usual helper methods on `Result` and `Option` do not work with `async` (see links below). However, these methods are mostly about transforming the `Result` / `Option` which you are not doing. Hence, your code could be rephrased to the following (assuming you want to return the result of the `match` expression):

```rust
let result = second_db.player_create(player_id).await;
if result.is_err() {
    first_db.player_delete(player_id).await?;
}
result
```

This omits the "mapping" part of both branches and is, in my opinion, easier to understand.

---

Related discussions:

- [How to use async/await inside closure of `Option::and_then` or `Option::map` without using OptionFuture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69844843/13679671)
- https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-run-async-code-within-option-result-function-chain/64053